# searching inside the file not working correctly

Tags: c++, file

/* in this program i have problem with my searchfile function. It is a function that will check in the file associated with the fstream whether the passed roll no. is already present in file or not. Unfortunately it is going in infinite loop. So what is the cause and solution for this problem */

NOTE:the file which searchfile is searching has contents like this:-

234|45|-1|-1|-1|-1|

325|56|-1|-1|-1|-1|

so there are 19 characters in each line of file.we will read the roll no. eg.234 then we must skip 19-4=15 characters to read next roll no.So we must go to 16 character.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
struct student{
    char roll[4];
    char name[30];
    char branch[20];
};
struct course{
    char cid[3];
    char name[10];
    char credits[2];
};

//buffer class to pack student struct details
class buffer_s{
    public:
    char buf[200];
    void pack(student &s);
};

void buffer_s::pack(student &s){
    buf[0]='\0';
    strcat(buf,s.roll);
    strcat(buf,"|");
    strcat(buf,s.name);
    strcat(buf,"|");
    strcat(buf,s.branch);
    strcat(buf,"#");    
}
//buffer class to pack course struct details
class buffer_c{
    public:
    char bufc[200];
    void pack(course &c);
};

void buffer_c::pack(course &c){
    bufc[0]='\0';
    strcpy(bufc,c.cid);
    strcat(bufc,"|");
    strcat(bufc,c.name);
    strcat(bufc,"|");
    strcat(bufc,c.credits);
    strcat(bufc,"#");   
}
//operator overloading for getting input of student struct
istream &operator >> (istream &in,student &s){
    cout<<"enter roll no. :";
    in.getline(s.roll,4);
    cout<<"enter name : ";
    in.getline(s.name,30);
    cout<<"enter branch : ";
    in.getline(s.branch,20);
    return in;
}
//operator overloading for getting input of course struct
istream &operator >> (istream &in,course &c){
    cout<<"enter course id no: ";
    in.getline(c.cid,3);
    cout<<"enter course name : ";
    in.getline(c.name,10);
    cout<<"enter credit ";
    in.getline(c.credits,2);
    return in;
}
//for searching whether the passed "roll" is already present in the file or not
int searchfile(fstream &fin,char roll[]){
    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);


    char word[4];

    int f=0;
    if(fin.good())
    {
    fin.getline(word,3,'|');

    word[3]='\0';
    while(!fin.eof()){

        cout<<"test"<<endl;//for testing the infinite condition of loop

        if(!strcmp(roll,word))
        {f=1;break;}


        else{
        fin.seekg(16,ios::cur);//16 since total characters in a line of file 3 is 20.4 already read so 20-4=16.
        fin.getline(word,4,'|');    
        word[3]='\0';
        }

        }
    }
        fin.clear();

    if(f==1)
    return 1;


    else
    return 0;   


}

//for putting things into r_detail file
void fillreg(fstream &file3,student &s,course &c){
    file3<<s.roll;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<c.cid;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<-1;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<-1;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<-1;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<-1;
    file3<<'|';
    file3<<endl;    
}

int main(){
    buffer_s s;
    buffer_c c;


    student ss;
    course cs;


    fstream file1;
    fstream file2;
    fstream file3;


    file1.open("s_detail.dat");
    file2.open("c_detail.dat");
    file3.open("r_detail.dat");

    int k=0;

    //k=2 for taking 2 inputs only.

    while(k<2){
    file3.clear();
    file3.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    cout<<"enter student details: "<<endl;
    cin>>ss;
    cout<<"enter course details: "<<endl;
    cin>>cs;
    cout<<endl;


    int x=searchfile(file3,ss.roll);
    cout<<x<<endl;

    if(!x)
    {
    s.pack(ss);
    file1.clear();
    file1.seekp(0,ios::end);
    file1<<s.buf;
    file1<<endl;
    }

    c.pack(cs);
    file2.clear();
    file2.seekp(0,ios::end);
    file2<<c.bufc;
    file2<<endl;

    file3.clear();
    file3.seekp(0,ios::end);

    fillreg(file3,ss,cs);
    k++;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is horrendous.  You may want to read the entire line instead of reading the first few characters and then attempting to scan the rest.  Additionally, `while (!fin.eof())` is bad practice; stop it now!

Comment: Also, variables ... **name them** (e.g. `k` and `x` are not good variable names).

Answer (score 0):

`main` loops while `k<2`, and `k` is incremental if `searchfile()` returns `0`. If the program is in an infinite loop, the `searchfile()` cannot be returning `0` in enough calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this code and with this question.

The reason your solution isn't working is that you've written a lot of code without testing any of it. Look at this:

```
fin.getline(word,3,'|');
```

Do you know what this assigns to `word`? You were expecting `234`, right? Did you check? Even if all the code you wrote after this were flawless (which it isn't) it might not do you any good because of this bug. Did you check your `while` loop to verify that it terminates correctly, in both cases (the number is present or it isn't)?

The solution is to isolate the part of the code you're working on (like this function), start with something small and simple, get it to work perfectly even if it doesn't do very much, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

One nice side effect of this approach is that if a bug appears and you can't see it, at least you know where it is to within a few lines, and you can post a very short, self-contained example for us to look at.

Also, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by learning the C++ tools:

```
int word;
fin >> word;
```